# How can I disable Authorization header cache in Ruby On Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have developed a `stateless` `RESTful` API in Ruby On Rails. The way it works is that when you log in you receive a token, that you then use as an `Authorization` header to make requests.

There are two different roles available in the API: an Admin role and a Client role.

What I have done is add some role constraints to the routes so I can have the same endpoint pointing to different methods in the controller based on the specific role, like so (from config/routes.rb):

`get '/courses', to: 'courses#admin_index', constraints: admin_constraints
 get '/courses', to: 'courses#client_index', constraints: client_constraints`.

The constraints are implemented like this:

`admin_constraints = RoleRouteConstraint.new(User::ROLES[:admin])
 client_constraints = RoleRouteConstraint.new(User::ROLES[:client])`

Where the RoleRouteConstraint retrieves the user that the Authorization header token belongs to, checks it's role and returns true if the role matches the constructor parameter.

The problem is that when I switch roles, Rails somehow caches my Authorization header from the previous role. Meaning that after I log in in the admin panel (as an admin), interact with the interface, and then go into the client interface, perform some actions, the API will keep my role as a client. If I then try to perform admin-specific actions, like so:

`put '/courses/:id', to: 'courses#update', constraints: admin_constraints`

I will not be able, since the API thinks I'm still logged in as a client. The thing is that it will work if I restart my rails server. Locally I'm using POW and in staging/production I'm using apache2. So if I perform a Rails restart and repeat the request as an admin, then it will work.

Anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: why are you using constraints for the routes?

Comment: The reason I'm using constraints for the routes is because I want to make requests to the same endpoints, but return different results depending on roles (permissions, availability, etc). In order to do that, I've decided to make different controller methods. Therefore I point the same endpoint to different methods in the controllers.

Comment: I think a better approach, would be to handle the authorization on the controllers, using, whether cancancan or pundit gems

Comment: I'll try to remove the constraints code to see if the problem persists and post updates. Is it because the code is in the config/routes.rb?

Comment: It should not be, but I think handling this thorugh the routes file can be overwhelming and can lead you to places you don't want to go.

Try using cancancan or pundit